# I've created a basic food menu in AngularJs. But I'm not able to add the comments as perfectly as it should be

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myController', myController) 
.factory('menuCtrlFactory', menuCtrlFactory);

myController.$inject =['menuCtrlFactory'];

function myController(menuCtrlFactory){

    var add=this;
    

    var shoppingList= menuCtrlFactory();
    
    add.items= shoppingList.getItems();

    add.itemName="";
    
    add.addbutton=function(){
    shoppingList.addbutton(add.itemName);
    
}


}
function menuCtrlService(){
  var service= this;

  var items=[{  

          dish:'Uthapizza',
             category: 'mains',
             label:'Hot',
             price:'4.99',
             description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
             
            
              },

              {  

          dish:'Uthapizza',
             category: 'mains',
             label:'Hot',
             price:'4.99',
             description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
             
            
              },
           

             ];
  
  
  service.addbutton=function(itemName){

           var item={
      name: itemName
    };

    items.push(item);
  
};
 
 service.getItems= function(){
    return items;
  };
}


function menuCtrlFactory(){

  var factory= function(){

    
    return new menuCtrlService();
  }

  return factory;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Shopping Menu</title>
  </head>
  <body>

 <h1>Food Menu</h1>
<div ng-controller="myController as menuList">

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="l in menuList.items">
<h2>{{l.dish}} 
<span>{{l.label}}</span>
<span>{{l.price | currency}}</span>
</h2>
<p>{{l.category}}</p>
<p>{{l.description}}</p>
<p>{{l.name}}</p>
<p>Enter Your Comments: <input type="text" ng-model="menuList.itemName">
<button ng-click="menuList.addbutton();">Add Comments</button></p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
  </html>
```

hello friends, I'm new to angular Js. I've created a basic food menu with the ability to add comments. But, as you can see from the code, after typing in the comments and clicking the add button, the comments are not displaying as it should be. The input textbox is again repeating and also I want to display the comments after each food item.Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are adding comments as new items which is wrong.

I've introduced a new attribute `comments` for each item in the items array. And using that to store comments and to render them.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myController', myController) 
.factory('menuCtrlFactory', menuCtrlFactory);

myController.$inject =['menuCtrlFactory'];

function myController(menuCtrlFactory){

    var add=this;
    

    var shoppingList= menuCtrlFactory();
    
    add.items= shoppingList.getItems();

    add.itemName="";
    
    add.addbutton=function(item){
    shoppingList.addbutton(item);
    
}


}
function menuCtrlService(){
  var service= this;

  var items=[{  

          dish:'Uthapizza',
             category: 'mains',
             label:'Hot',
             price:'4.99',
             description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
             comments: []
            
              },

              {  

          dish:'Uthapizza',
             category: 'mains',
             label:'Hot',
             price:'4.99',
             description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
             comments: []
            
              },
           

             ];
  
  
  service.addbutton=function(item){

    item.comments.push(item.newComment);
  
};
 
 service.getItems= function(){
    return items;
  };
}


function menuCtrlFactory(){

  var factory= function(){

    
    return new menuCtrlService();
  }

  return factory;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Shopping Menu</title>
  </head>
  <body>

 <h1>Food Menu</h1>
<div ng-controller="myController as menuList">

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="l in menuList.items">
<h2>{{l.dish}} 
<span>{{l.label}}</span>
<span>{{l.price | currency}}</span>
</h2>
<p>{{l.category}}</p>
<p>{{l.description}}</p>
<p>{{l.name}}</p>
<p ng-repeat="comment in l.comments">{{comment}}</p>
<p>Enter Your Comments: <input type="text" ng-model="l.newComment">
<button ng-click="menuList.addbutton(l);">Add Comments</button></p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: thanks bro for the help. but one thing I have not understood  in your code <button ng-click="menuList.addbutton(l);">Add Comments</button></p>.Why is the one used for??

Comment: ng-model for the comment input is 'l.newComment'. When user clicks the add button the function 'menuList.addbutton' is called with the argument 'l'. 'l ' is the item itself. In the function the newComment is taken and added to the comments array of the item.

Comment: bro thanks for the help. If you dont mind could you help me a more little. i'm not understanding this lines of code.  
                                                                 
    service.addbutton=function(item){

    item.comments.push(item.newComment);
  
};                                                                                                                       Could you explain a bit here.why you are declaring the item and again using newComment. It's bit confusing. Could you simplify a little.

Comment: I'm maintaining an array for each item in the item.comments attribute. I'm just storing a new comment of an item on item.newComment attribute. And in the addbutton function I use this attribute to add the new comment to the comment array of the item.

Answer (score 0):

At last got a demo running, as i saw:
- because every input got the same model update all input values as once
- need to got a array of inputs model
- need to pass index to update service items
- add comments to each object

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13428/)

```
 <h1>Food Menu</h1>
<div ng-controller="myController  as menuList">

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="l in menuList.items">
<h2>{{l.dish}} 
<span>{{l.label}}</span>
<span>{{l.price | currency}}</span>
</h2>
<p>{{l.category}}</p>
<p>{{l.description}}</p>
<p ng-repeat="comment in l.comments">{{comment}}</p>
<p>Enter Your Comments: <input type="text" ng-model="menuList.itemNames[$index]">
<button ng-click="menuList.addbutton($index);">Add Comments</button></p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myController', myController) 
.factory('menuCtrlFactory', menuCtrlFactory);
myController.$inject =['menuCtrlFactory'];


function myController(menuCtrlFactory){
    console.log('ooo');
    var add=this;
    this.itemNames=[]


    var shoppingList = menuCtrlFactory();

    add.items= shoppingList.getItems();

    //add.itemName="";

    add.addbutton=function(index){
        console.log(index, this.itemNames[index]);
        shoppingList.addbutton(this.itemNames[index], index);
    }


}
function menuCtrlService(){
  var service= this;

  var items=[{  

             dish:'Uthapizza',
             category: 'mains',
             label:'Hot',
             price:'4.99',
             description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
             comments:[]

              },

              {  

             dish:'Uthapizza',
             category: 'mains',
             label:'Hot',
             price:'4.99',
             description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',

                comments:[]
              },


             ];


  service.addbutton=function(itemName, index){

           /*var item={
                name: itemName
                };*/
    console.log(itemName);
    items[index].comments.push(itemName);

};

 service.getItems= function(){
    return items;
  };
}


function menuCtrlFactory(){

  var factory= function(){


    return new menuCtrlService();
  }

  return factory;
}
```